# Why does the link from Membership Dashboard give a search with the wrong results

Tags: civimember

On Membership dashboard you can click on numbers in right column to 'see details' but the number of results is different to that on the dashboard.

This may also affect other Dashboard click-throughs such as on Events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitted the PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6911.

The issue was occuring due to the recent change made in Search form as per which field(s) will have entity info in their name (membership_)status_id (also for uniqueness) rather then status_id which raises ambuiguity when we process the param for building whereClause because there are other table that can share same column name e.g. contribution.status_id.

Answer (score 1):

The url is /civicrm/member/search?reset=1&force=1&status=1,2,3&type=1&owner=1

which suggests the results should filter by Status and Primary but the Status filters are not applied on the search, hence you see 'all' results, rather than just the New, Current and Grace.

Have added a [Jira issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17353) for this bug and hope to provide patch at some point.

Comment: For some of the links, some of the filters work eg

civicrm/member/search?reset=1&force=1&status=1,2,3&type=1&owner=1

does give

Membership Type(s) In General ...AND...
Primary Members Only

but Status is not working. I tested with just a single Status and no commas but no improvement